# how to install GEM package availble for python in GitHub?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, installation, python-embedding

I want to install a python package availble in GitHub (https://github.com/palash1992/GEM) named GEM (graph embedding methods). but I dont know how and from which point should I start. Can anyone give a step by step installing instruction? I dont have git on my computer. Should I have install it first? For more information I have python 3.7 version on my system.

1. I already tried using: pip install GEM command in cmd.
2. pip install git+git://github.com/palash1992/GEM.

Non of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/palash1992/GEM#install ?

Comment: I solved the issue installing                                                                                       1.git software on my system and                                                                           2.add git.exe and cmd file in windows path.                                                                                          3.then typing this command in my cmd prompt:                                                           "pip install git+https://github.com/palash1992/GEM"                                                           but thanks for contributions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tino said, your answer could be in the GitHub readme file. Here are the instructions:

The package uses setuptools, which is a common way of installing python modules. To install in your home directory, use:

```
    python setup.py install --user
```

Just copy and paste the above line into your command prompt and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

use this command: pip install nxt-gem.

it works for me.